# Data breach chance with azure devops/portal

Tags: azure-devops, azure-security

This is not a really code based question but I was thinking of how Azure portal and devops are secure if it available over the internet and no need to use VPN.

So I mean any one who has credential can login from any places and download any thing without company consent and its huge risk for any company which is on azure devops for git (not enterprise ) and even azure portal.

Sorry again as I asked this question just out of my curiosity...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Data breach chance with azure devops/portal

Indeed, in today’s workplace, users can work from anywhere, on any device. Whether using a company-provided laptop at the office, working from home, traveling for business, or using a personal mobile phone, employees expect to seamlessly access what they need to get work done. However, not all devices, apps, or networks are equally secure. To secure your environment/device, we need flexible security policies that are responsive to conditions.

[Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) conditional access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview) is a good choice

You could set some Common signals to limit the `IP Location information`, `Device` and so on:

[image]

Hope this helps.